# surjective and preserves standard norm on $ \mathbb{R}^n $ implies linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, lie-groups, orthogonality, quadratic-forms

If a surjection f: $ \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n $ satisfies
$$
\langle f(v),f(v)\rangle =\langle v,v\rangle =\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2
$$
for all $ v $ then must $ f $ be a linear transformation?

Here is my attempt at a proof. By

[Could a non-linear transformation be orthogonal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2165880/could-a-non-linear-transformation-be-orthogonal)

it is enough to show that $ f $ satisfies
$
\langle f(u),f(v)\rangle =\langle u,v\rangle 
$
for all $ u,v \in \mathbb{R}^n $. Normally I would conclude that $ f $ preserves the inner product from the fact that $ f  $ preserves the norm
$$
 \|f(v)\|=\|v\| 
$$
together with the polarization identity.
$$
\langle u,v\rangle =\frac{\|u+v\|^2-\|u\|^2-\|v\|^2}{2}=\frac{\|f(u+v)\|^2 -\|f(u)\|^2-\|f(v)\|^2}{2}
$$
and
$$
\langle f(u),f(v)\rangle =\frac{\|f(u)+f(v)\|^2-\|f(u)\|^2-\|f(v)\|^2}{2}
$$
But I am not assuming additivity of $f$, $f(u+v)=f(u)+f(v)$, so preserving norm and preserving inner product are no longer equivalent (at least not because of the usual argument).

If this is false then give an example of a surjective $ f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n $ satisfying
$$
\langle f(v),f(v)\rangle =\langle v,v\rangle =\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2
$$
which is not linear. Preferably your counterexample $ f $ should be a homeomorphism (continuous with continuous inverse). Even better, $ f $ should be written in terms of specific recognizable (preferably analytic) functions. I'm also curious what is the group of all invertible $ f $ that preserve standard norm on $ \mathbb{R^n} $? Just the $ n \times n $  orthogonal group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated, the answer is no.

For example, let $S^{n-1}$ be the unit sphere in ${\mathbb R}^n$ and let $\phi: S^{n-1}\to S^{n-1}$ be any diffeomorphism (i.e. bijective differentiable map), then define
$$ 
f(v)=|v|\cdot \phi\Big(\frac{v}{|v|}\Big),
$$
then $|f(v)|=|v|$.

This $f$ is continuous. And differentiable except at $0$. We can modify this construction to make $f$ differentiable everywhere.

On the other hand, if you assume $\langle f(u), f(v)\rangle =\langle u, v\rangle$, then
the answer is yes.

Comment: Thanks Yuval! Can you give an example of such a $ \phi $ which is not an orthogonal transformation, perhaps for $ n=3 $? Perhaps by writing $ \phi $ as a recognizable analytic function?

Comment: For example you can use spherical coordinate to describe $\phi$; e.g. use the notation $x=\sin \alpha\cos\beta$, $y=\sin\alpha\sin\beta$, $z=\cos\alpha$, where $0\leq \alpha\leq \pi$  is the angle with $z$-axis... One can for example take $\phi$ to be the map that maps $(\alpha,\beta)$ to $( h(\alpha), \beta)$, where $h$ is any smooth increasing function so that $h(t)=t$ near $t=0$ and near $t=\pi$.